# Query for rows by timestamp with timezone via index

Tags: postgresql

i have the following condition:

`where s.event_time AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'>= ?`

There is an index on "event_time", and it is used if i say

`where s.event_time >= ?`

Adding the timezone calculation seems to break that. Is there an easy way to fix this?
My naive idea would be to do a  "reverse time zone calculation" on the parameter instead of the field.
So if "at time zone x" adds 5 hours to the field, i need to subtract 5 hours from the parameter. Is there a function for that?

Comment: What is the data type of `event_time`?

Answer (score 0):

DB cannot use indexes when we are using any functions or any casting operations with `WHERE` clause. For using indexes we must create functional indexes. Create index with using time zone.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX table_index_name ON yourtable USING btree ((event_time AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'));
```